# How to return to gdb prompt after continuing and gdb have not hit the breakpoint

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

(gdb) target remote machine-XYZ:5001
(gdb) b some_function_name
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Now here the remote process have not hit the function and gdb is still in continuing stage. But if I have to add more break point or if I have to detach how can I do that, this can't be done without returning to prompt.

Answer (score 6):

Use control-c to interrupt.  This will bring you back to the gdb prompt, where you can enter commands.

Comment: The problem with this is the remote process is getting stopped and I dont want to do that

Comment: If you have multiple threads you can look at gdb's scheduler locking feature, in conjunction with target-async.  If you don't, then you are just out of luck.  I really understand why you have this constraint, though.

Comment: FYI, I have to press ctrl-c twice.  I have not looked into why.